# An example of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be an arbitrary metric space, and define
>   $$p(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)} \quad \forall x,y \in X.$$
>
> Show that
>
> a) $(X,p)$ is a metric space
>    b) All convergent sequnce in $(X,d)$ and $(X,p)$ are the same

I did the $p(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and
for all $x,y \in p(x,y)=p(y,x)$ but I couldn't show the triangle inequality for part A and I couldn't do anything for part b.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try noting that $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ is monotone increasing and $f(0)=0$ (you have $p=f·d$). This is just an hint

Comment: thanks for your help I solved it. what about part b do you think anything

Comment: I wrote an answer to $(b)$ for convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the triangle inequality, note that
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}=1-\frac{1}{1+t}$$
is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Now let $x,y,z\in X$, if $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)$ or $d(x,z)\leq d(y,z)$, we immediately conclude that $p(x,z)\leq p(x,y)+p(y,z)$. So let's assume that
$$d(x,z)\geq d(x,y)\geq d(y,z).$$
It follows that
$$p(x,z)\leq\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,y)}\leq\frac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)}\leq p(x,y)+p(y,z).$$
This proves the triangle inequality.

For part (b), if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$, then clearly $p(x_n,x)\to 0$. Conversely if $p(x_n,x)\to 0$, note that
$$1+d(x_n,x)=\frac{1}{1-p(x_n,x)}\to 1.$$
Thus we conclude that $d(x_n,x)\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

For the point $(b)$ we can also note that being $p=f·d$ where $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is (continuous) encreasing, we have that (for $\varepsilon<1$) $B'_\varepsilon(x)=B_{f^{-1}(\varepsilon)}(x)$ where $B'$ and $B$ denote the balls w.r.t. $p$ and $d$ respectively. So $p$ and $d$ induce the same topology (the euclidean one).